# How to create shapetext using Java

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create shape texts directly using codes as the number of shapetext i need may vary.
I tried using the code below, and I created the shapes in a collection (with type shapetext). When I use "traceln(text.getX());" it prints 2500 but I do not see the text anywhere on the screen. May I understand what I have done wrongly and how can I make the shapetext be shown? Do I have to add shapetexts into my network/level and initialize it?

Thank you for your help!

```
    ShapeText text = new ShapeText(SHAPE_DRAW_2D3D, true, (double) 2500, (double) 3000, (double) 0, 0, black, "testing", new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 100), ALIGNMENT_CENTER );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have successfully created the text, but you need to add it to the presentation to be shown

Simply add

```
presentation.add(text);
```

An alternative option if you have an undetermined amount of texts is to rather create a single text object and then replicate it as many times as you want to show it. Once you add a replication to a presentation object a local variable called index is now available for you to use in many of the fields.

Use this in the dynamic text field to get the values you want to display (like in the example below I stored the texts in a collection)
And you also use this index to change the position of the text (See what I have done in the Y coordinates)

[image]